# Display multiple select as normal select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a multiple select [like the following](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple).

But what I now need is to display it like a normal "dropdown" select, because there are many normal selects on my website and it looks very strange if theres a select with size more than 1.

So the multiple select should also [look like here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select).

I don't want to include an extra jQuery plugin or something else. I look for a easy html/css/js solution.

Comment: Without plugins, you can't. Plugins hide the native select element and it builds a "dropdown" with divs

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude that's not true at all. The plugin does it with regular JS.

Comment: if `<select .. multiple size="1">` does not meet your requirements, you may build your own UI element using plain javascript and html, and using the css property `overflow: scroll;`. You can also specify a bit more which scroll should appear using `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Marcos means that you need some sort of javascript plugin to do this, not a browser plugin. Of course, these plugins are regular JS, so you _can_ do this yourself, but the __easy__ html/css/js soution is to just use a plugin, because someone has done the work for you. If you do it yourself, you are building a ...plugin, so there's no real difference, except there's a fair chance it won't be as good

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel. You would need to build your own functionality. Use a plugin. Select2 is one of the best: https://select2.github.io/

Comment: @MatthewHerbst you don't understand me. You need some javascript plugin, doesn't matter what library you use or don't use any library, but native select dropdowns can't make that OP wants.

Comment: I recommend chosen. https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: jQuery-ui multi select plugin also works nice: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

Comment: Thanks all for your answers.. I will try some of these plugins, even though I don't want to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick class (pure JavaScript) that should behave as you wish. You'll probably want to add some more functionality.

EDIT: Updated the code, forgot you wanted a dropdown

https://jsfiddle.net/xLtfsgbd/1/

```
 ( function()
{

  var MultipleSelectDropDown = function() 
  {
   // constructor
  }

  MultipleSelectDropDown.prototype =
  {
    options: [],
    selected: [],
    size: 0,
    displayed: false,

    add: function(element)
    {
      this.options.push(element);
      this.size = this.size + 1;
    },

    remove: function(element)
    {
      for(var stored in this.options)
      {
        if(this.options[stored] == element)
        {
          this.options.splice(stored, 1);
          this.size = this.size - 1;
          break;
        }
      }
    },

    render: function(onIdSelector)
    {
      var container = document.getElementById(onIdSelector);
      if(typeof container == 'undefined')
      {
        window.alert('The list container is undefined!')
        return;
      }

      var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
      mainDiv.setAttribute('style', 'width:300px; height: 50px display:block;');
      var firstItem = document.createElement('div');
      firstItem.setAttribute('style', 'width:250px; height:25px;');
      firstItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.options[0]));
      var dropDownArrow = document.createElement('img');
      dropDownArrow.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-down-128.png');
      dropDownArrow.setAttribute('style', 'width:25px; height:25px;');

      _self = this;
      dropDownArrow.onclick = function(e)
      {
          if(_self.displayed)
          {
                _self.displayed = false;
              var displayedList = document.getElementById('daList');
              document.body.removeChild(displayedList);
          }
          else
          {
                var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            _self.renderList(rect.left, rect.top);
                        _self.displayed = true;
          }
      };

      firstItem.appendChild(dropDownArrow);

      mainDiv.appendChild(firstItem);
      //mainDiv.appendChild(dropDownArrow);
      container.appendChild(mainDiv);
    },

    renderList: function(x, y)
    {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.setAttribute('id', 'daList');
      div.setAttribute('style', 'positon:absolute; top:'+y+'; left:'+x+'; height:100px; width:200px; overflow-y:scroll; background-color:#fff;');
        var list = document.createElement('ul');

      var _self = this;
      for(var stored in this.options)
      {
        var option = this.options[stored];
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.setAttribute('index', stored);
        listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(option));

        listItem.onclick = function(e)
        {
          var index = this.getAttribute('index');
          if(index < 0 || index > _self.size)
          {
            return;
          }

          var selected = this.getAttribute('selected');
          // Item not selected
          if(selected == null || selected == '' || selected == 'false')
          {
            this.setAttribute('selected', 'true');
            this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#0099ff;');
            selected.push(option);
          }
          else // Item selected
          {
            this.setAttribute('selected', 'false');
            this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#fff;');

            for(var sel in _self.selected)
            {
                if(_self.selected[sel] == option)
                {
                  _self.selected.splice(sel, 1);
                }
            }
          }
        };

        list.appendChild(listItem);
      }

      div.appendChild(list);
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
  SelectDrop = MultipleSelectDropDown;
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you ask for is **simply not possible**. Your target look is a select box rendered by the web browser. You simply can not modify a multiple select to be rendered the same way. How would the user select multiple items?

For usability reasons I **strongly** suggest looking at another solution. Multiple selects are *really* hard for users to understand. A *far* more usable solution would be to use a group of checkboxes.

Or as [WebAIM states it](http://webaim.org/techniques/forms/controls):

> It is recommended that multiple select menus be avoided. Not all browsers provide intuitive keyboard navigation for multiple select menus. Many users do not know to use CTRL/Command or Shift + click to select multiple items. Typically, a set of check box options can provide similar, yet more accessible functionality.

More regarding usability and multiple select, see for example :

- http://www.90percentofeverything.com/2008/12/03/multiple-select-controls-must-evolve-or-die/ or
- http://alistapart.com/article/sensibleforms

This being said, there are multiple libraries which creates a *custom* experience, such as https://github.com/bsara/multi-select-dropdown.js (no dependency)

Comment: Feel free to elaborate as to why you choose to down vote this.